# Issues to copy and paste from a workbook (loop error)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through a folder of excel files (around 6 files or so), copy data from a named table and paste values into a master. I've tried using the DataBodyRange instead of standard range but i'm having problems with it pasting into ThisWorkbook (where the master will live).  The paste destination is the same size as source and should be pasted on next empty row,so on and so forth. I'm two days into banging my head on the wall and can't figure this out.Any help or insight would be amazing.

```
Sub SalesTrackerCompiler()

Dim Myfile As String, str As String, mydir As String, wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    mydir = "C:\Users\$$$$$$$$$$$$\"
    Myfile = Dir(mydir & "*.xlsm")
    ChDir mydir
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Dim erow As Long


    Do While Myfile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (Myfile)
    With Worksheets("Data Input Table")
    Worksheets("data input table").ListObjects("DataInputSource").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Set rng = ListObjects.Item(1).DataBodyRange.Select
    rng.Copy wb.Worksheets("regional source data").Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)


    ActiveWorkbook.Close True

    End With
    Myfile = Dir()

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Your dynamic book is not explicitly defined which may be the issue. Try `Set new_book = Workbooks.Open (MyFile)' .... and then, `With new_book.Sheets("Data Input Table".......`

Comment: Hi urdearboy, the file where the code, master and paste destination live is where i'm trying to designate as ThisWorkBook. This would already be open. When i run i get error 424 Object Required on the "set Rng" line.

Comment: On what line???

Comment: on "Set Rng = ListObjects.Item(1).DatabodyRange.Select" line

Comment: Oh, remove the `.Select`. I also dont see where you have `Dim rng as Range` anywhere in your code

Comment: Just tried removing the .select and adding Dim Rng as Range but the same 424 error pops up.

Comment: Well like I initially said, it's prob because it doesnt know what workbook/sheet your `ListObjects` is in. This list object is unqualified which means your code is guessing where that object is. If it guesses wrong, you get your error

Answer (score 0):

Add a break point to the line where you know the error is, run your code, when it stops use the immediate window and type `?ListObjects(1).Name` press enter and see if you get the same error, I suggest you will.

You need to reference the specific Workbook and Worksheet to to get the ListObject. Try changing

`Workbooks.Open (Myfile)`

to

`set new_workbook = Workbooks.Open(Myfile)`

then use (assuming the ListObject is in Worksheet 1)

`Set rng = new_workbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange`